# Remote validation is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I entered value for email in textbox it didn't fire VerifyUserEmail method. Below is my code. Where is my mistake?

> View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Email, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Email)
        </div>
</div>
```

> Model

```
[DisplayName("Email")]       
[Remote("VerifyUserEmail", "User", ErrorMessage = "Email already exists!")]
public string User_Email { get; set; }
```

> Controller

```
    public JsonResult VerifyUserEmail(string User_Email)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RKDYMEntities objConnection = new RKDYMEntities())
            {
                ObjectParameter objIErrorCode = new ObjectParameter("ErrorCode", typeof(Int32));
                ObjectParameter objBFlag = new ObjectParameter("bFlg", typeof(bool));
                objConnection.Check_User_Exists(User_Email, objBFlag, objIErrorCode);

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(objBFlag.Value) != true)
                {
                    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I have also added `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in web.config.

Below is generated html code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="User_Email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Email must be a string with a maximum length of 200." data-val-length-max="200" data-val-remote="Email already exists!" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.User_Email" data-val-remote-url="/User/VerifyUserEmail" id="User_Email" name="User_Email" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="User_Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
       </div>
 </div>
```

> Jquery Validation

I am using client side JQuery validation which is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Registration").validate({
        rules: {
            User_Email: {
                required: true, email: true
            },
            User_Password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            User_ReTypePassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                equalTo: '#User_Password'
            },
            User_FirstName: { required: true },
            User_LastName: { required: true },
            User_ZipCode: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            User_Email: {
                required: 'Email is required', email: 'Invalid email'
            },
            User_Password: {
                required: 'Password is required',
                minlength: 'Min length of password is 8'
            },
            User_ReTypePassword:
                {
                    required: 'Confirm Password is required',
                    equalTo: 'Confirm Password must be equal to password'
                },
            User_ZipCode: { required: 'ZipCode is required', digits: 'Only digits are allowed' },
            User_FirstName: { required: 'First Name is required' },
            User_LastName: { required: 'Last Name is required' }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    });
});
```

> Edit

I have removed

`$("#Registration").validate({
    //        rules: {`
and it's working.

Any idea? Why?

Comment: Try adding `[AllowAnonymous]` to method `VerifyUserEmail`

Comment: Are you using and including jquery, jquery.validate, jquery.validate.unobtrusive?

Comment: @Mackan.Yes, all are correctly loaded.

Comment: @RahulNikate.Tried `[AllowAnonymous]` . Didn't succeed.

Comment: I have only one  time`@using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Registration" }))`.

Comment: Several sources talk about `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` being needed on the controller (so `User controller` in your case). Mind giving that a try? Feels like a hack, but perhaps it can help debug the issue.

Comment: Regarding your update, client validation: When you have special chars in your client validation you should enclose the names with quotes. So: `"User_email":` and so on. Perhaps this was throwing an error that stopped the remote validation from kicking in.

Comment: Why are you not just adding the `[Required]`, [Compare]` attributes to your model properties (meaning you don't need any of this script? When you call `.validate()` you wipe out the rules added by jquery.validate.unobtrusive` so the `[Remote]` wont work. It will probably work if you load `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` after your script, but since you seem to prefer to manually writing all the scripts, just handle the `.change()` event of the textbox and call the method using ajax and just delete unobtrusive validation

Answer (score 3):

The error message from the data attribute is never used (You can test this by using my simple example below):

```
[Remote("VerifyUserEmail", "User"]
```

Remote accepts an overload with an error message but does nothing with it, you should return the error message from the server-side.

Basically anything other than a true return is the error message sent back to the client. If you add the message instead of returning false you should see this.

```
 return Json(string.Format("{0} does not exist.", User_Email),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You also need to ensure you have the following references:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Simple working example**

Model

```
public class AModel
{
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [Remote("VerifyUserEmail", "Home")]
    public string User_Email { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult VerifyUserEmail(string User_Email)
    {

            if (User_Email == "1")
            {
                return Json("No", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
    }
```

View

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Email, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Screen shot

[image: screen shot 1]

[image: screen shot 2]

Comment: OPs action is not even getting hit - surely that cannot be the cause.

Comment: Are you sure, as i am also using `Remote Validations` in one of my project with the `ErrorMessage` attribute and it's working fine.

Comment: `RemoteAttribute` can take an `ErrorMessage`

Comment: @hutchonoid I can buy that the ErrorMessage won't get processed correctly, but I would be surprised if it just stopped the action from getting called. Meh, I've been wrong before :) (not saying I am quite yet though)

Comment: @Mackan Don't worry I'm wrong all the time, not ruling myself out just yet but this helps us learn from it. :)

Comment: @Mackan Hi, well it does actually hit it still but the attribute ErrorMessage is never used. I have updated the question to reflect that, so you are correct it does take it but does nothing with it. I think the issue is with the references but will see when the correct answer is accepted. Clarifies it further for me though, been a good question.

Comment: @Mackan Interesting to know that the error message does still allow it to be hit server-side, I've learnt that now. My previous understanding was incorrect. :)